# phpmyadmin: how to save changes made on multiple rows using "edit"

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, phpmyadmin

Using an "find and replace" chrome's app, I made some changes in the fulltext field of 300 joomla articles.

I could save each row one by one using the "go" button under each row (cf picture) but is there a way to save all the change (made in several rows) in once?  I did try to use the "go" button at the bottom of the edit page but without success.

here is the query:

```
SELECT `fulltext` 
FROM kms_content
WHERE catid
IN ( 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22 ) 
LIMIT 0 , 500
```

[image: the editing option]
[image: go button to save a single row]
[image: go button at the bottom]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE kms_content SET fulltext = REPLACE (fulltext, 'text to find', 'text to replace') WHERE catid IN (16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22);
```

Comment: thank you but I do need to replace some html character (such as ;" />)  I'm afraid it won't work between the  '...'

Comment: It should work. Try it.